# Laravel 4 - beginner stupid error

Tags: laravel, routes, navbar, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

i'm learning Laravel and i created a project.

I'm working on the navbar, the structure is the following :

- Navbar contains 2 links : one to the root / the other to a "liste_sites" route
  the liste_sites route calls the 'accueil' route with a boolean set to 1 to indicate which kind of information i have to display

Here's the code :
**routes.php file**

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@accueil', 'as' => 'accueil'));
Route::get('liste_sites', 'HomeController@liste_sites');
```

**HomeController.php file**

```
private function gen_accueil()
    {
        return View::make('accueil',  array('which_actif' => 0));
    }

    public function accueil() 
    {

        return $this->gen_accueil();
    }

    public function liste_sites() 
    {
        return View::make('accueil', array('which_actif' => 1));
    }
```

The template contains this in the code :
**template_mynet.blade.php file** (into )

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/mynet/public">Accueil</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @yield('navigation')
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

**The navigation.blade.php file**

```
@section('navigation')

<li>{{ link_to('liste_sites', 'Liste des sites', null, ($which_actif == 1)? array('class' => 'actif'): null )}}</li>

@stop
```

**And the accueil.blade.php file**

```
@extends('template_mynet')

@include('navigation')

@section('content')

@if ($which_actif == 1)
    HI BOY
@endif

@stop
```

Now, everything works fine, when clicking on the "accueil" or "liste_sites" from the navbar, it displays what i want.
But when i'm on the page
**/public/liste_sites**
and i click again on it from the navbar... chrome says this **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.**
I'm not really able to understand why it won't work.

I noticed that when i click again on it, the URL changes from

```
http://localhost/mynet/public/liste_sites
```

to

```
https://localhost/mynet/public/liste_sites
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are your paths. You should use `URL::to()` or `URL::route` (if you had named routes) to make it work as it should. Now some paths are relative to the current url so the href attribute is appended to the current path.

You could add names to your routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@accueil', 'as' => 'accueil'));
Route::get('liste_sites', array('uses' => 'HomeController@liste_sites', 'as' => 'lists_sites');
```

And now you could use

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::route('accueil') }}">Accueil</a>
```

and instead of `link_to` you could now use `link_to_route` helper because your route have now name.

Comment: Where should i use it ?

Comment: It is working. I understand now.
Can you just edit your answer to add the 'uses' at the second route ?
Thanks